# Mapping integers to k-ary trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Is there an algorithmic way to map the natural numbers to unique k-ary trees?

I am familiar with the work of Tychonievich who created a mapping from integers to binary trees. https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lat7h/blog/posts/434.html

Is there something similar for k-ary trees?

Comment: See my similar question at: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346647/mapping-integers-to-k-ary-trees?noredirect=1#comment867839_346647

Comment: The comments on mathoverflow are correct that using the binary tree solution with base-$k$ instead of base-$2$ representations just works.

Comment: Yeah, I posted my answer about 7 hours ago. But then I realised that graphs would look the same (for a root + one child) no matter which child it is. However this is also the case with Luther's blog post (link in question). So, yes, base-k works.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there are other ways of doing it..

Answer (score 0):

One easy way of doing it could be like so:
Convert the natural number n into base k to get $n_k$.

Now suppose that the digits of $n_k$ are $(0,d_1,d_2,...,d_m)$.
Example, for n=5 and k=4, digits of $n_k$ would be (0,1,1).

Coming to the tree now.
Let the tree's root node have a value of $0$, so, if $n=0$ then we simply return the root.

If $n\ne0$, then we proceed to generate our tree from root. From the root, we take $d_1$$^{th}$ child node, and from there take $d_2$$^{th}$ child node and then continue doing it. That is, from $d_i$$^{th}$ node we would take $d_{i+1}$$^{th}$ child node of $d_i$.

For instance, when k=4, following is the graph, where vertex labels represent which $n_k$ would bring you there:

[image: example 1]

Now, when I want a graph for, say, 10 - I simply give the subgraph of above graph having the following vertices: 0 (root), 02 and 022.

Also observe that each vertex in the graph has a unique base-k value, the next graph shows these values in base-10:

[image: example 1 values]